# MvxSpinner with Button in MvxDropDownItemTemplate

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I want to have a MvxSpinner with a drop down template that has a button in it.  The button click brings up a webbrowser with information about that item.  The button click works fine, but now the item cannot be selected.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an mvx issue - more a general android question.

Comment: Since the button takes the touch event away from the spinner the item is not selected. It is not an Mvx issue and you should reconsider your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to make this work.  Not sure if it is best practices, but it works for me.

I made the ItemsSource for the Spinner an enumerable of view models.  There is a command for the button click and an event to handle any other touches in the item.  I subclassed MvxSpinner and MvxAdapter.  In the subclassed adapter I assign the event to a handler that programmatically clicks the back button to close the drop down list.  I also routed a method from the adapter to the spinner in order to set the selected item.

```
public class ButtonSpinner : MvxSpinner
{
    public ButtonSpinner(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        var adapter = new ButtonAdapter(context, routedItemClick);
        adapter.ItemTemplateId = Adapter.ItemTemplateId;
        adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId = Adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId;
        adapter.SimpleViewLayoutId = Adapter.SimpleViewLayoutId;
        this.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void routedItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetSelection((int)sender);
    }
}

public class ButtonAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
    EventHandler<Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs> _routedItemClick;
    View _parent;

    public override IEnumerable ItemsSource {
        get {
            return base.ItemsSource;
        }
        set {
            base.ItemsSource = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in value)
                {
                    var dialectItem = item as DialectItemViewModel;
                    dialectItem.DialectSelected += (object obj, EventArgs args) => {
                        var dialectItems = ItemsSource as List<DialectItemViewModel>;
                        _routedItemClick(dialectItems.IndexOf(dialectItem), null);

                        _parent.RootView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.Back));
                        _parent.RootView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.Back));
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ButtonAdapter(Context context, EventHandler<Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs> routedItemClick) : base(context)
    {
        _routedItemClick = routedItemClick;
    }

    protected override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
    {
        if (_parent == null)
            _parent = parent;

        return base.GetView (position, convertView, parent, templateId);
    }
}
```